# Translate API to convert only text portion (and not HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-translate, microsoft-translator

I have some text content in an HTML file which I need to dynamically translate to diff languages based on user input. I am using the Microsoft Translator AJAX interface to do the same.

Now the HTML file is something like;

```
<h1><u>CSS3 Media Query Support in IE7/8<o:p></o:p></u></h1>
<p class=MsoNormal>Some other text content to be translated as well ...Some other text content to be translated as well ...Some other text content to be translated as well </p>
```

Now this is just a small snippet which I have shown here. Actually it is a huge markup (with lots of styling tags)

I use the API as below for translation;

```
s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?oncomplete=mycallback&appId=8B841CA7C1A03443682C52AD07B7775A7BD5B3AA&from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&text=" + text;
```

Ref for the same is
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512404

My question is if there is any way by which I can only pass the text to be translated (and the tags should be ignored). I know innerText property can be used instead of innerHTML. But the downside is I get only raw text output as response for which I need to recreate the HTML for the styling.

Comment: Alright, let me see if I understand this. You have some files saved in MS's goofy MSO HTML format. You want to strip out all of the structure, have it translated, returned and then reapply the structure to the translation? Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely what i want....though whichever way it can be done...i am open to that...

Answer (score 0):

You might have success by simply making sure that you include `contentType=text/html` in the Translate API call, for text acquired using innerHTML.

Otherwise, you need to walk your html, pull out the text to translate a section at a time, possibly call the BreakSentences API to pull out individual sentences, translate, then replace with the translation. It will be more efficient to batch up the segments and call TranslateArray. The approaches can be blended, by walking the html and only passing sections with inline markup.

You may be forced to walk the html anyway to fit the text that is being passed into the size limits of the API.